# on-connect icecast method - ideas on finding out who is listening to the stream

Tags: php, authentication, audio, streaming, icecast

So I have a website that you need to log in to and once you are authenticated a cookie is set with a unique session variable (as well as the obligatory db insert with an ip address to say they are logged in) I can use to identify the individual concerned.

I want to be able to identify exactly who is listening to the icecast audio stream.

So I'm using the on-connect process to be able to capture who is requesting to listen, Icecast will pass me ip address, agent as well as a number of other variables. it then updates a table with a flag they are listening and on-disconnect flags the amount of time they listened.

So to summarise:

1. Logon
2. Log session/ip to DB
3. Into Website / App
4. Play stream
5. OnConnect - add agent and "Streaming" flag (based on ip)
6. OnDisconnect - Add time listened (based on agent and ip)

The problem comes that I can have people either listening on multiple devices (tablet/laptops) at the same time (or they switch from one to another within a space of a few minutes) or there are multiple logons at the same ip (behind a firewall for example).

I dont really want to use http based authentication  in the traditional sense (ie user:pass@domain.com) as more and more browsers are phasing this out. So what are my options for getting an idea of exactly who is who ?

current scripts are based on php, but am quite happy to play with something else if the need arises.

Comment: Specifying basic auth via URL is definitely not being phased out.  What browser is giving you trouble with it?  In any case, this is usually handled by some sort of token that allows a user to play a stream.  It's saved in a database and then added to any stream links and playlists when the authenticated user requests them.  I don't know how to handle this scenario in Icecast, but this is possible with a service I run called the AudioPump CDN.  It isn't generally available at the moment but will be soon.  E-mail me at brad@audiopump.co if you can't get this working with Icecast.

Comment: I can't find the original link talking about it however this link (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489)  describes that IE's default behaviour is to ignore the username/password in the url path and re-request the details. I'm sure the other link saw chrome remove the functionality only for it to be re-added.

Comment: Regarding the token authentication stream - I think your right - the workflow would be Click Link > Authenticate User (Cookie/sessionID & DB) script > This script would pass-thru the stream rather than directly. The script would somehow have to keep tabs on the clientID from Icecast (although maybe not - I'm still pondering that)

Comment: The way my system works is by hitting a URL on your server when a new listener connects.  It connections a connection ID as well as all of the request information and headers.  The script on your server can tells the streaming server to allow or disallow the connection, and then the streaming server does all the work.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you already have a cookie, if you make sure that it's valid also for the URL of your Icecast server, then you can use that cookie in your URL-auth.

Specifically in the [Icecast documentation on URL auth](http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/auth.html#stream-auth) the section about *headers* and *header_prefix*. Just ensure that the cookie headers are forwarded to your backend and you both can authenticate them AND know their identity.